# How to create custom leaflet popup style in Shiny/R

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, leaflet

The task at hand is simple--I want to be able to customize the CSS style of my Leaflet popups within a Shiny app. I've tried to combine solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881931/including-js-css-scripts-in-shiny-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606141/how-would-i-customise-the-look-and-feel-of-the-leaflet-popup) example to no avail.

Using both of the above linked solutions, here is some (failed) example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(

      tags$head(includeCSS(system.file('www', 'style.css', package = 'myPackage'))),

      leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "800")
    ), #END UI


  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addCircles(lng = -80, lat = 30, radius = 100, popup = as.character("Test"))
    }) #END RENDERLEAFLET
  }
)
```

The style.css file looks like this and is saved in the `www` folder inside my Shiny app directory:

```
<style>

.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
  background: #DB0925;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:24px;
  }
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper a {
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
  width:30px;
  height:15px;
  }
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-tip {
  border-left:15px solid transparent;
  border-right:15px solid transparent;
  border-top:15px solid #2c3e50;
  }
</style>

<div class='custom-popup' id='map'></div>
```

I suspect that the path to my css file is the issue. When I run this code as is, I get the following error:

> Warning in file(con, "r") :   file("") only supports open = "w+" and
>   open = "w+b": using the former

Any solutions how to get this to work?

Comment: You are referencing your css the wrong way. Take a look here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html If you just change the tag$head for `theme = "style.css"` it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icaro Bombonato led me to the solution! Instead of       `tags$head(includeCSS(system.file('www', 'style.css', package = 'myPackage'))),`, all that was necessary was `includeCSS("style.css")` in the UI. The `style.css` file was also housed in my main Shiny directory rather than the www folder.